# Dispatch Truck Timeline. How to populate projects into a single timeline?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote some code last night to roughly get a Dispach Truck interface going for the place I work at. The code below works, but I was hoping to create jobs and display them in the same 2400 military hour time span. I think it has to do with loops or perhaps you have a better implementation?

**Front End Screen Shot**

[Link to Front-End Static & Generated HTML](http://nexlevel.io/dispatch.php)

[image: Front End Screen Shot]

**! Desired Outcome Screen Shot !**

[image: Desired Outcome Screen Shot]

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

  // SEARCH TEAM DISPATCH ASSIGNMENTS HERE 

    // Check to see if this run of the script was caused by our insert submit button being clicked.
    //if (isset($_GET['insert-submit'])) {

      $dis_team      = 'RED';

      //$dis_event     = (isset($_GET['dis_event']) ? $_GET['dis_event'] : null);
      //$dis_date      = (isset($_GET['dis_date']) ? $_GET['dis_date'] : null);
      //$dis_time_from = (isset($_GET['dis_time_from']) ? $_GET['dis_time_from'] : null);
      //$dis_time_to   = (isset($_GET['dis_time_to']) ? $_GET['dis_time_to'] : null);

        //INCLUDE DB CONNECTION STRING
            include 'db.php';


            // Concatenated SQL table fields and wild card query.
            $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_dispatch WHERE DIS_TEAM = :dis_team");

            //Bind the wild card to its corresponding parameter.
            $stmt->bindParam(':dis_team', $dis_team, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            // Execute this SQL statement.
            $stmt->execute(); 

            // Fetch & Populate all rows returned in var $result. 
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

      // If the search record was found, populate it on the html table.
            if (($result !== false) && ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)) {


            // FOR EACH row returned...
            foreach( $result as $row ) {

        // RESET $i for each row returned..
        $i = 0;
        $inc_50 = 50;

            // find time_from start offset
            $dis_time_from = $row['DIS_TIME_FROM'];
            // find time_to end offset
            $dis_time_to   = $row['DIS_TIME_TO'];

            // Heading & progress-bar for each scheduled assignment.
            // Pad possible zeroes on the left due to military time format.
            echo '                  <h6 class="mb-1">' . sprintf('%04d', $dis_time_from) . ' - ' . sprintf('%04d', $dis_time_to) . ' <span class="badge badge-danger">Lead Tech - Stephen Clark</span></h6>' . "\n";
            echo '                  <div class="progress mb-1" style="height: 30px;">' . "\n";

            $inc_50 = 50;

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 48; $i++) {

            $inc_50 += 50;

        // RED
            if( ($inc_50 >= $dis_time_from) && ($inc_50 <= $dis_time_to) ) {

            echo '                    <div class="progress-bar bg-danger text-white" role="progressbar" style="width: 4.8%" aria-valuenow="4.8" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">&nbsp;</div>' . "\n";

            } else {
            // GREY
            echo '                    <div class="progress-bar bg-dark" role="progressbar" style="width: 4.8%" aria-valuenow="4.8" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">&nbsp;</div>' . "\n";

            }           

            }

            echo '</div>' . "\n";

            }


            }

            $link = null;
            $stmt = null;

    //}

?>
```

**TBL_DISPATCH Screen Shot**

[image: tbl_dispatch Screen Shot]

Comment: `...hoping to create jobs and display them in the same 2400 military hour time span`. Not clear (to me, at least) what exactly what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps another layout mocked up with the results that you'd like to see would be helpful?

Comment: You got it. Coming up.

Comment: Something tells me it's the scope of the loop... My brain hurts on nested loops.